# D3 Sankey diagram from CSV rendering incorrectly

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, svg

I am trying to make a Sankey Diagram using d3js. I am using a csv data source and using code based on this block: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c9b90689c1438f57d649

My dataset is quite large, but I think I should be under the threshold where I would be breaking the SVG renderer. I am unsure though. My code is functional when running with the 1082 line "SankeyDataSampleFunctional.csv". Here is what it looks like:
[image: working code]

I have made some slight modifications to the original codebase to allow for my diagram to have substantially larger amounts nodes at some layers while others don't. This is my attempt at accommodating it in sankey.js:

```
 function initializeNodeDepth() {
  var ky = d3.min(nodesByBreadth, function(nodes) {
    if (nodes.length > 200){
      return (size[1] - (nodes.length - 1) * 1) / d3.sum(nodes, value);
    }
    else if (nodes.length > 1000) {
      console.log((size[1] - (nodes.length - 1) * 1) / d3.sum(nodes, value))
      return (size[1] - (nodes.length - 1) * 1) / d3.sum(nodes, value);
    }
    return (size[1] - (nodes.length - 1) * nodePadding) / d3.sum(nodes, 
    value);
  });
```

I'm doing this to clamp down the space between nodes on layers with large numbers.
But when I try to add the last layer with 2102 more nodes I get all sorts of problems. This is what it looks like when I plug in "SankeyDataSample1.csv" into the same code in question:

[image: first bug]

I checked the console and its saying I'm trying to draw a bunch of stuff with negative height. My first recourse was to clip 2101 of those 2102 extra nodes off, to see if i could get just one node to render correctly on the following layer. of course not:

[image]

I tried adding some additional depth to that branch and it continues to render the branch in the wrong direction:

[image]

finally, i checked this post about someone else who was using large datasets in a d3 sankey: [Large data set breaks d3 sankey diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579174/large-data-set-breaks-d3-sankey-diagram)

I attempt the 'quick fix' of forcing my height to be nonzero seen in this post:

```
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy < 0 ? 0 : d.y; })
```

However this didnt do much for me. I also tried multiplying negative values of d.dy by -1 with a hope to invert them and this is all i got:

[image]

Here is my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/g2rE0z?p=info

Am I up at the limits of SVG with that last 2k nodes? Or am I just going about this wrong? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to enlarge canvas size? Usually, in my case, if there's no space left for nodes, it renders like that.

Comment: yea it ended up being canvas size, i had to go way larger than expected to accomodate the nodes. thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see the answer that I've posted here: [Large data set breaks d3 sankey diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579174/large-data-set-breaks-d3-sankey-diagram/66983218#66983218)
The idea is that you can regenerate the graph with a new width and a new height until each node has a proper height.